# Let's face it, Frontend web development can be a minefield with all the different moving parts involved

Tags: american-english, british-english

What's the meaning of this line "Let's face it, Frontend web development can be a minefield with all the different moving parts involved "

I know what "Let's face it" is.
I know what "minefield" is.

I just can't figure out the meaning in the above sentence.

Source of the information is https://youtu.be/Qms4k6y7OgI?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hw1g77I35ZivVLe8k2nvjB&t=51

Comment: Suppose you are working to include component X and have almost completed it when the component X guys say "Sorry, we've just released a major revision." The parts are moving, as with [shifting sands](https://www.lexico.com/definition/shifting_sands).

Comment: Lots of moving parts: https://www.yourdictionary.com/lots-of-moving-parts

Comment: All the moving parts of the project create a minefield, which means that frontend development is tricky and dangerous.